# Are listeners removed when directive is destroyed?

Tags: vue.js

Here's a simple options object for a directive. When the directive is destroyed what happens to the event listener? Is it stuck in memory or is it removed?

```
export default {
  inserted (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      console.log('Click!')
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's your responsibility, in the `unbind` hook

```
function listener () {
  console.log('Click!')
}

export default {
  inserted (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', listener)
  },
  unbind(el) {
    el.removeEventListener('click', listener)
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this could cause an issue if you use `v-if` upstream to toggle your component on/off because `v-if` will remove the <input> element from the DOM before the `beforeDestroy` lifecycle method is called in the component. It's definitely a problem with beforeDestroy, but I suspect `unbind` may suffer the same issue caused by `v-if` removing elements from the DOM tree while the Vue instance still exists.

Comment: So while debugging your component, make sure you test conditionally-rendering it with `v-if` in the parent component. You will either see an error message about "removeEventListener of null" or `unbind` will have worked great.

Comment: it doesn't work if I use a dynamic property inside function.